# Can a non-zero curl vector force field still do a null amount of work?

Tags: vector-fields, conservative-field

I've been given a vector field $\vec{F}=(12xy^2, 12yz, 9z^2)$ in cartesian coordinares and I'm asked to calculate the work it would develop on a particle moving from point $A$ to point $B$ through various paths. The problem itself is very simple, but it has led me to consider some questions with a deeper physical meaning.

If you compute the curl of the field, you can tell $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{F}=(-15y, 0, -24xy) \neq 0$ unless $y=0$. Therefore, 2 questions arise, the latter more general than the former:

1. Does this mean the field could be considered conservative as long as the particle stayed fixed in the plane $y=0$?
2. For some general vector field $\vec{F}$ with the property $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{F}\neq 0$ in any point, could we still find some closed path $\mathcal{P}$ such that, if we computed the path integral of our vector field following it, we could obtain $\oint_{\mathcal{P}} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} = 0$? I'm assuming we can't, because in that case Stokes' theorem would be violated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Question 1:

Recall from Stokes' theorem that $$\oint \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{l} = \int (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}) \cdot d\vec{a}.$$So any path that can be spanned by a surface for which this latter surface integral vanishes will have no net work done on it.  In your example, since $(\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F})_y = 0$, this means that any curve confined to a plane of constant $y$ will have no net work done it on a closed path (as you have correctly concluded.)  Note also that in a plane of constant $y = y_0$ we have
$$
\vec{F} = (12x y_0^2, 12 y_0 z, 9 z^2)
$$
and if we assume that there is some kind of constraint force ensuring that $F_y = 0$ then the total force on the particle is
$$
\vec{F}_\text{tot} = (12 x y_0^2 , 0 , 9 z^2) = - \vec{\nabla} ( - 6 x^2 y_0^2 - 3 z^3)$$
showing that the particle can explicitly be thought of as moving in a conservative force field in this case.

###### Question 2:

As a trivial example, the path integral $\oint_{\mathcal{P}} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} = 0$ if the closed path $\mathcal{P}$ consists of a curve from point $A$ to point $B$ followed by the same curve in reverse, even if $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} \neq 0$.

More generally, the statement of the theorem you're thinking of is basically that under appropriate conditions on smoothness of the fields and curves,

> If and only if $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} = 0$ at all points in space, then for all curves $\mathcal{P}$, $\oint_{\mathcal{P}} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} = 0$.

The contrapositive of this statement is not

> If and only if $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} \neq 0$ at some points in space, then for all curves $\mathcal{P}$, $\oint_{\mathcal{P}} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} \neq 0$.

but

> If and only if $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} \neq 0$ at some points in space, then *there exists* a curve $\mathcal{P}$ for which $\oint_{\mathcal{P}} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} \neq 0$.

In other words, the theorem still allows for there to be curves for which $\oint_{\mathcal{P}} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} = 0$ even when $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} \neq 0$;  there just have to be *some* curves for which the path integral does not vanish.  (Remember, the negation of a "for all" statement is not another "for all" statement, but a "there exists" statement.)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot for your answer! You solved my doubts in a simple yet effective manner!

Answer (score 0):

1. The vector field is the vector field, which is non Conservative. along y=0 we could define some other vector field F'(x,z)= <0,0,0> this vector field is Conservative and so bodies moving on the xz plane exclusively, would say that this field is Conservative

2.imagine  the curl of a vector field being defined in such a way such that from e.g x<0 the curl is 1 and from x>=0 it is -1. Here we have a vector field whose curl is never zero, and yet a line integral whose boundary is symettric about these two regions would yield zero.

** I am also pretty certain that this is consistent with the divergence being zero everywhere for the curl, as a guassian pillbox on the boundary yields zero for its surface integral**